# Matlab: access ith-element returns index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, class, indexing

I would like to copy an element of a column vector into another. However I do not understand how to access the ith-element. Here's what I tried:

```
>> I1_inliers

I1_inliers = 

  1300×1 SURFPoints array with properties:

              Scale: [1×1300 single]
    SignOfLaplacian: [1×1300 int8]
        Orientation: [1×1300 single]
           Location: [1300×2 single]
             Metric: [1×1300 single]
              Count: 1300

>> I1_inliers(2)
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 1x1 stuct. If you want the 2nd element in the array you need to do

```
I1_inliers.Scale(2)
```

Comment: So what is the 1300×1 SURFPoints array? I want to access the second SURFPoints in order to copy it into another variable